# Temporarily Disable Sql Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

Due to a business need, I may need to disable transactional replication in my environment (Sql 2k -> Sql 2008). Functionally, I understand this to mean that I will need to drop subscriptions and articles. Is getting the create scripts enough to restore replication back to original state when the conflicting need is addressed?

Thanks.

Comment: A couple of questions.  Do you want to disable just the subscriber or the publisher and the subscriber ? Are you replicating the entire database or are you filtering out some objects?

Comment: We would need to disable it on both the publisher and the subscriber. Also, we are replicating a large subset of the tables in the database, but not all of them.

Comment: I just put in my answer based on disabling the subscription.  The subscription would be disabled on both the publisher and subscriber.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested this example using SQL Server 2000 (MS2000) as the publisher and SQL Server 2008 (MS2008 )as the subscriber.  On the publisher, one database called arp has several tables, but only the table users is included as an article in the publication. This example removes the subscription from the both servers and then puts it back again.

**On the Subscriber MS2008**

**Removed the existing subscription from MS2008**

```
USE arp
GO

EXEC sp_droppullsubscription @publisher='MS2000', @publisher_db='arp', @publication='arp_pub'
```

**On the publisher MS2000**

**Dropped the Subscription**

```
-- dropped subscription
exec sp_dropsubscription @publication = N'Arp_pub', @subscriber = N'MS2008', @destination_db = N'arp', @article = N'all'
```

**Dropped the Subscriber**

```
-- On MS2000, dropped subscriber from MS2008 after removing it from MS2008
exec sp_dropsubscriber @subscriber = N'MS2008'
```

Later on, I recreate the subscription.

**On the Publisher, MS2000**

**Add back in the subscriber**

```
use [master]
exec sp_addsubscriber @subscriber = N'MS2008', @type = 0, @description = null, @security_mode = 1, @frequency_type = 64, @frequency_interval = 1, @frequency_relative_interval = 1, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 4, @frequency_subday_interval = 5, @active_start_time_of_day = 0, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 0, @active_end_date = 99991231

exec sp_changesubscriber_schedule @agent_type = 1, @subscriber = N'MS2008', @frequency_type = 4, @frequency_interval = 1, @frequency_relative_interval = 1, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 8, @frequency_subday_interval = 1, @active_start_time_of_day = 0, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 0, @active_end_date = 99991231
GO
```

**Add back in the subscription**

```
use [Arp]
exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'Arp_pub', @subscriber = N'MS2008', @destination_db = N'arp', @sync_type = N'Automatic', @subscription_type = N'pull', @update_mode = N'read only'
GO
```

**On the Subscriber MS2008**

**Create the database**

```
CREATE DATABASE arp;
GO
```

**Add the pull subscription**

```
use [arp]
exec sp_addpullsubscription @publisher = N'MS2000', @publication = N'Arp_pub', @publisher_db = N'Arp', @independent_agent = N'False', @subscription_type = N'pull', @description = N'', @update_mode = N'read only', @immediate_sync = 0
```

**Add the agent**

The @job_login is a ntlm user that has rights to the default snapshot folder.  That user also has access to the publication on the publisher

The snapshot folder is a shared folder accessible by both Publisher and Subscriber.

```
exec sp_addpullsubscription_agent @publisher = N'MS2000', @publisher_db = N'Arp', @publication = N'Arp_pub', @distributor = N'MS2000', @distributor_security_mode = 1, @distributor_login = N'', @distributor_password = null, @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False', @frequency_type = 64, @frequency_interval = 0, @frequency_relative_interval = 0, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 0, @frequency_subday_interval = 0, @active_start_time_of_day = 0, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 20120214, @active_end_date = 99991231, @alt_snapshot_folder = N'', @working_directory = N'', @use_ftp = N'False', @job_login = N'MS2008\replication_user', @job_password = 'test123', @publication_type = 0
GO
```

**On the publisher MS2000, I ran the snapshot job**

The replicated table was once again visible on MS2008.

Comment: Your welcome.  I did leave in place the users, snapshot folder, shares.  All this does is remove the subscription from both servers, but everything else is left alone.